# Не работает условия if/else в jQuery. При нажатие на клавишу должно появляться меню

Tags: css, jquery, if, условия

```js
$(document).keydown (function(event){
  if($(event.code) == ("KeyM")){
    $("#mobil_menu").addClass("open_menu");
  }
  if($(event.code) == ("Escape")){
    $("#mobil_menu").removeClass("open_menu");
  }
  console.log(event);   
});
```

```css
#mobil_menu{
    width: 237px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #00BF96;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 85px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    float: right;
    left: -220px;
    top: 0;
    transition: right ease 1s;
}
#mobil_menu:hover{
    left:0;
    transition: right ease 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="mobil_menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item4</a></li> 
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле Вы искали свойство `event.originalEvent.code`

Не забудьте кликнуть в `iframe` сниппета иначе он не слушает нажатия

```js
$(document).keydown (function(event) {
  console.log(event.originalEvent.code);
  if (event.originalEvent.code === "KeyM") {
    $("#mobil_menu").addClass("open_menu");
  }
  if (event.originalEvent.code == "Escape") {
    $("#mobil_menu").removeClass("open_menu");
  }
});
```

```css
#mobil_menu{
    width: 237px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #00BF96;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 85px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    float: right;
    left: -220px;
    top: 0;
    transition: 200ms;
}
#mobil_menu.open_menu, 
#mobil_menu:hover{
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="mobil_menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item4</a></li> 
  </ul>
</nav>
```